# How to reference object variable from within method

Tags: python

I'm still learning to work with objects. I defined vertices() as a method to return the vertices (initialized as vs) in Graph. I know that there is a more concise, elegant way to write vertices() but exactly how is escaping me.

Also specifically this relates to exercise 2.5 in Think Complexity: http://greenteapress.com/complexity/html/book003.html#toc12

```
class Graph(dict):
    def __init__(self, vs=[], es=[]):

        for v in vs:
            self.add_vertex(v)

    def add_vertex(self, v):
        """Add a vertex to the graph."""
        self[v] = {}

    def vertices(self):
        v = []
        for i in range(len(self)):
            v.append(i)
        return v
```

Comment: I think `add_vertex` and `vertices` methods should be indented.

Comment: They should -- I wasn't pasting directly and that's my mistake.

Comment: Also, don't use lists as default argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Also the first for-loop should be part of the init, right?

Comment: Yes, code should be fixed now.

Comment: Shouldn't you actually be returning the keys of the dictionary, rather than a range of integers from 0 upwards? How exactly is the calling code supposed to use the result of `vertices`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it one line with a list comprehension:

```
def vertices(self):
    return [i for i in range(len(self))]
```

Comment: Or just `return range(len(self))` for that matter.

Comment: Haha yeah that too (as long as you're using python 2x)

Comment: In 3.x, `list(range(len(self)))` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

> I defined vertices() as a method to return the vertices (initialized
>   as vs) in Graph.

As `vs` in `__init__` contains keys of the dict, i guess this is what you want.

```
    def vertices(self):
        return self.keys()
```

If so, you don't need `vertices` method at all - just always use `Graph.keys()`